# SQL Insert multiple record while using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a query that inserts multiple data in one go as a single query.

```
INSERT INTO tableName (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3) 
SELECT 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'test4', 'test5', 'test6'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'test7', 'test8', 'test8'
```

Using the above code, is there a way to implement the 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'? 
Something like:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3)
SELECT 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COLUMN_1='new', COLUMN_2='new', COLUMN_3='new'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COLUMN_1='new', COLUMN_2='new', COLUMN_3='new'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COLUMN_1='new', COLUMN_2='new', COLUMN_3='new';
```

Note: May be irrelevant or pointless, but I'm doing this with mysql workbench.

Comment: Your first insert query is invalid. You can't union all INSERT statements.

Comment: @KamilG. - Sorry, my mistake. How do I edit the question for me to fix it?

Comment: Click on the grey edit button below tags in your post.

Comment: What keys do you have on your table? Why use a select when a values clause would seem more appropriate?

Comment: @KamilG. Edited. Please see updated question

Comment: @P.Salmon Would you kindly show how to do so as a response? The 'SELECT' part is only something I found in the internet which works for me. Basically all i want is to insert multiple records in one go. With my question, I want to implement the On Duplicate Key Update with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is basically correct, just get rid of the intermediate `ON DUPLICATE KEY...`. There is no need for a derived table because you are not referencing columns from the union.

```
INSERT INTO tableName (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3) 
SELECT 'test8', 'test9', 'test10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'test4', 'test5', 'test6'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'test9', 'test5', 'test6'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COLUMN_1='new', COLUMN_2='new', COLUMN_3='new';
```

The problem you are going to run into is if you get more than one duplicate key on the `INSERT`. In that case the `UPDATE` will attempt to set two rows to have the same key ('new') and the `INSERT` will fail. You could potentially work around this by changing the query so that the `UPDATE` includes part of the old column value. In this case since you'll be referring to a column value you will need a derived table:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3) 
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'test8', 'test9', 'test10'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'test4', 'test5', 'test6'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'test1', 'test5', 'test6') AS dt
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COLUMN_1=CONCAT('new', COLUMN_1), COLUMN_2='new', COLUMN_3='new';
```

[Updated SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f55175)

Comment: Question: What happens if the first one is a duplicate, and so is the second one, or the third one, etc.? Will they all be having similar records now?

Comment: Yes & no. It will cause an error, since they will end up with the same value for the key ('new'), and no inserts will happen. So trying to update with constant values can't work if you get two or more duplicate keys from the same `INSERT`.

Comment: So would that mean, this is not advisable? I was thinking, for every insert, there is a duplicate key update that would specify what the record would be if it is a duplicate. Having to set it (the duplicate key update) at the very end might cause an issue which as much as possible, I'm trying to avoid even if it is to be caught (via try-catch). Any idea how else I could do it?

Comment: Thanks for the update! Sorry but I don't seem to understand what you mean in your last two statements: "You could potentially work around this by changing the query so that the UPDATE includes part of the old column value. In this case since you'll be referring to a column value you will need a derived table". Could you please explain?

Comment: If you look at my new query, you'll see the `UPDATE` on `COLUMN_1` now uses part of the old value to create the new value. This should help prevent duplicate key errors if more than one of the inserted data has a key which matches one already in the table. Since this `UPDATE` now refers to a column in the `UNION`, the rules (as pointed out in the links provided by the other answers) mean that you must use a derived table (so we use `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... UNION ... UNION ...) AS dt`)

Comment: I think I understand now. Last question: How is it able to determine if it's a duplicate record? By every data in every field? Or is it based on the primary key/s?

Comment: It's based on the primary and/or any unique keys. In my example SQLFiddle, I used a primary key on column_1 but I could just as easily have used a unique key on column_3 instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'test4', 'test5', 'test6'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'test7', 'test8', 'test8') AS derived_table
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COLUMN_1='new', COLUMN_2='new', COLUMN_3='new'
```

Explanation:

- You need to separate the `SELECT` and the INSERT statements. I.e. one `INSERT` can have only one `SELECT`. Then you can do `UNION`-s within the select.
- As stated on the [related manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... UNION` doesn't  support a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` -s. However, they support it on a derived table (a.k.a. subquery).

Comment: Question: What happens if the first one is a duplicate, and so is the second one, or the third one, etc.? Will they all be having similar records now?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified your primary key and unique indexes that you have, but nevertheless this will work - [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) mentions this case. Depending on your unique constraints if the row is found, all three column values will be updated (even if they are not part of the unique key).

```
INSERT INTO tableName (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3)
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'test4', 'test5', 'test6'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'test7', 'test8', 'test8'
) AS dt
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    COLUMN_1 = 'new'
  , COLUMN_2 = 'new'
  , COLUMN_3 = 'new'
```

To test this it's better to include some additional row since every value in your sample data is unique and you can't observe the behaviour.

Comment: Question: What happens if the first one is a duplicate, and so is the second one, or the third one, etc.? Will they all be having similar records now?

Comment: Answer: why don't you try it yourself? This is the best way to learn things. It's easy to set it up. I believe it should raise an error due to unique constraint violation for subsequent update.